# Python sklearn logistic regression K-hold cross-validation : how to create a drameframe for coef_

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation

Python3.5

I have a dataset stored in a varibale, `file`, and I try to apply 10 hold cross-validation with logistic regression. What I am looking for is the way to list the average of `clf.coef_`.

```
print(file.head())

   Result  Interest  Limit  Service  Convenience  Trust  Speed 
0       0         1      1        1            1      1      1   
1       0         1      1        1            1      1      1   
2       0         1      1        1            1      1      1   
3       0         4      4        3            4      2      3   
4       1         4      4        4            4      4      4
```

Here is a simple logistic regression code I've written in order to show a list of `coef_`.

[In]

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = file.drop(['Result'],1)
y = file['Result']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25)
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
accuracy = clf.score(X_test,y_test)
print(accuracy)

coeff_df = pd.DataFrame([X.columns, clf.coef_[0]]).T
print(coeff_df)
```

[Out]

```
0.823061630219  

             0          1
0     Interest   0.163577
1        Limit  -0.161104
2      Service   0.323073
3  Convenience   0.121573
4        Trust   0.370012
5        Speed   0.089934
6        Major   0.183002
7          Ads  0.0137151
```

Then, I tried to apply 10 fold cross-validation to the same dataset. I have a code below but I wasn't able to produce a dataframe of a list of coef_,`coeff_df`, like I did for the analysis above. Can someone provide solutions?

[In]

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10)
print (scores)
print (np.average(scores))
```

[Out]

```
[ 0.82178218  0.7970297   0.84158416  0.80693069  0.84158416  0.80693069
  0.825       0.825       0.815       0.76      ]
0.814084158416
```

Answer (score 3):

`cross_val_score` is a helper function that wraps scikit-learn's various objects for cross validation (e.g. `KFold`, `StratifiedKFold`). It returns a list of scores based on the `scoring` parameter used (for classification problems, I believe this will be `accuracy` by default).

`cross_val_score`'s return object does not allow you to access the underlying folds/models used in cross validation, meaning you cannot get each model's coefficients.

To get the coefficients for each fold of cross validation, you'll want to use `KFold` (or if your classes are imbalanced, `StratifiedKFold`).

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df = pd.read_clipboard()
file = pd.concat([df, df, df]).reset_index()

X = file.drop(['Result'],1)
y = file['Result']

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, random_state=0)

models, coefs = [], []  # in case you want to inspect the models later, too
for train, test in skf.split(X, y):
    print(train, test)
    clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
    clf.fit(X.loc[train], y.loc[train])
    models.append(clf)
    coefs.append(clf.coef_[0])

pd.DataFrame(coefs, columns=X.columns).mean()
```

Gets us:

```
Interest       0.000000
Limit          0.000000
Service        0.000000
Convenience    0.000000
Trust          0.530811
Speed          0.000000
dtype: float64
```

I had to make up data from your example (which only has one instance of the positive class). I suspect these numbers will not be 0 in your case.

---

**Edit**
Since `StratifiedKFold` (or `KFold`) gives us the cross validation splits of the dataset, you can still calculate the cross validation scores using the model's `score` method.

The below version is slightly changed from above in order to also capture the cross validation scores for each fold.

```
models, scores, coefs = [], [], []  # in case you want to inspect the models later, too
for train, test in skf.split(X, y):
    print(train, test)
    clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
    clf.fit(X.loc[train], y.loc[train])
    score = clf.score(X.loc[test], y.loc[test])
    models.append(clf)
    scores.append(score)
    coefs.append(clf.coef_[0])
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code works! One additional question - is there anyway to produce a list of scores based on your code? I want to set  'L1 penalty' and `cross_val_score` won't let me.

Comment: Updated the my answer to address this

Comment: For my data, I needed to use X.iloc[train] (iloc instead of loc)